# Place Popups in R Leaflet, from csv

Tags: r, csv, dynamic, r-leaflet

I want to concatenate multiple columns from a `csv` and show the data in a popup for its respective point in R, using `Leaflet`.
I have set the points from a `csv`, so that it is displayed in R, but from what I have read on the internet, the popups have to be set in `html`, and I don't know if it can be read from a columns in the `csv`.
This is my code:

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
m<-leaflet()
m

ct <- read.csv("data.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # Brings in the file 'ctlist.csv'
m<-leaflet(ct) %>%
  addTiles()%>%
  setView(lat=14.0818,lng=-87.20681,zoom=6)
m %>% addCircles(~lng, ~lat, popup=ct$type, weight = 3, radius=40, 
                 color="#ffa500", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8)
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered as is, you need to post some data, show the dataframe and spell out what you want in the popup or no one will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from `?addCircles`:

> popup a character vector of the HTML content for the popups (you are
>   recommended to escape the text using htmlEscape() for security
>   reasons)

But, because a plain character vector can also be interpreted as `HTML`, you do not have problem if you want to read it from a `CSV` o using any plain character vector:

Very small example:

```
m<-leaflet() %>%
  addTiles()%>%
  setView(lat=14.0818,lng=-87.20681,zoom=6)
m %>% addCircles(lat=14.0818, lng=-87.20681, popup="Hola", weight = 3, radius=40, 
                 color="#ffa500", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8)
```

[image]